# how to use subdomains in flask?

Tags: python, flask

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'This is the main domain.'

@app.route('/', subdomain='<subdomain>')
def subdomain(subdomain):
    return f'This is the subdomain: {subdomain}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this doesnt work i run it locally and localhost:5000 gives main and sub.localhost:5000 gives main not sub so, i add this to hosts file:

127.0.0.1 sub.localhost

but it didnt work it still just opens sub.localhost:5000 and shows main not sub and i tried hosting services like render and it gives error and ngrok tunnel from localhost gives error,how do i use subdomains and have them actually work??

so like how to make it work locally, and using tunnel services like ngrok and using hosting services like render

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `SERVER_NAME` variable first.

Try this, after setting your `website_url` properly:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

website_url = 'example.com:8000'
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = website_url

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'This is the main domain.'

@app.route('/', subdomain='<subdomain>')
def subdomain(subdomain):
    return f'This is the subdomain: {subdomain}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**UPDATE:**

How to test:

Assuming we stick with domain "example.com" and subdomain: "subdomain.example.com", define in your `hosts` file the 2 hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com subdomain.example.com
```

then make requests to:

- http://example.com:8000
- http://subdomain.example.com:8000

Comment: it doesnt work, i go to the given ip and port and it says this is the subdomain: 
even when im on the main page and gives this too in terminal
\flask\app.py:1883: UserWarning: Current server name '192xyz.x.xy:8000' doesn't match configured server name 'example.com:8000'
  return self.url_map.bind_to_environ(
192.xyz.x.xy - - [06/Mar/2024 14:31:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: , so i remove <subdomain> replace it with sub and now it gives 404 error and says
\flask\app.py:1883: UserWarning: Current server name '192.xyz.x.xy:8000' doesn't match configured server name 'example.com:8000'
  return self.url_map.bind_to_environ(
192.xyz.x.xy - - [06/Mar/2024 14:33:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: add having 127.0.0.1 sub.localhost in the hosts file has no effect when i remove it or add it its the same

Comment: you were supposed to set the `website_url` to your site, not keep the `example.com`. I updated the answer with steps to test the solution.

Comment: okayy it worked thanks, but what about when im hosting? if im hosting on render i have no way to edit a hosts file

Comment: also this only works locally, when i use something like ngrok or packetriot to expose the localhost to the internet it doesnt work i go to the base url it shows this is the subdomain: and when i go to subdomain.base_url it errors so i tired taking my ngrok url and changing example.com:800 to ngrokurl.com:5000 and changing the records too but it didnt work its giving weird errors so idk what to do about hosting and tunneling and also i dont want just subdomain i want any subdomain they go to not just subdomain.url if i make the record *.url will it work? will all subdomains work

Comment: by work i mean in flask i have it as <subdomain> and it shows the subdomain so i want all subdomains to show